# Prevent duplicate values in a calculated field on ms-access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am really new to access. I have a calculated field(Name) in my Table which consist of 3 short text fields (fName + mName + lName).

I want to prevent any duplication in the calculated field (Name).

Comment: ?? If the field is calculated (which you [shouldn't use](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html) anyway), you can't prevent duplicates in that. Maybe you want an Unique Index on fName + mName + lName?

Comment: thanks for the help creating a unique index did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a key using all three columns e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
( 
 fName VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL,
 mName VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL,
 lName VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE ( lName, fName, mName )
);
```

Note the order of the columns in the key may be important if it will form the clustered index for the table (i.e. how it is physically stored on disk). Not sure whether this can be done using the MS Access user interface.

Comment: Thank you for this. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Store a calculated field isn't good idea (because you provide redundancy of data in the database). Can you calculate that value within real fields values  on the fly on the form/query or other GUI?

To avoid duplicate data just create unique  key/index for real fields